# PiZero W connected to (GPIO): how to emulate PiZero with GPIO input on Mac OS X

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, gpio, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a Raspberry PiZero W that is connected via GPIO pins to a flowmeter. This machine is at work, and I'd like to be able to debug my attempt at the flowmeter code that was wonderfully suggested in this SO post: [PiZero W connected to two peripherals (GPIO and USB): how to continuously read from both at same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492080/pizero-w-connected-to-two-peripherals-gpio-and-usb-how-to-continuously-read-f) while at home. I don't care as much about having wifi and network connectivity on the simulated machine, simulating GPIO inputs to the Pi is the most critical function.

Some details about the system:
PiZero W is running Buster OS on 32bit ARM.
Flowmeter is connected to PiZero W via GPIO 17 which is an SPI connection. The basic version of the flowmeter code that I am using can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/MattHawkinsUK/rpispy-misc/raw/master/python/hall.py

I would like to emulate this set up with a simulated Flowmeter that is actually sending signals to the Pizero on my home machine: Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64. I also have VirtualBox installed, but not sure if that's the best option.

Is this possible?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Can you `ssh` or VPN into work maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately not.