# How to model and simulate sensors that will send data to raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, simulation, communication, sensors, modeling

I am trying to establish communication between laptop and RPI. So far, I have used python and socket programming to do that. Now, instead of using actual sensors, I want to simulate sensor behavior by which sensor data can be sent from laptop to RPI.

So far I came across some options to do it:

1. Using IMB Bluemix IoT simulator or
2. Using simple python scripts to create sensor data or
3. Using simulink sensor models

Can anyone give me a better idea or any comment about these options please?

Comment: There are a couple of simple solutions in the answers here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521903/2836621

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how Redis is going to help me to model & simulate sensors. It is a data server right? So I have to write a python program for sensor behavior and the stuff them into Redis?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question then... I thought you wanted a method of exchanging data rather than a simulator. There's a decent `simpy` tutorial here... https://realpython.com/simpy-simulating-with-python/