# How to communicate between two raspberry pi via Bluetooth and send sensor data from one pi to another?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm working for some school project. I want to send temperature sensor data from one raspberry pi 4 to another pi 4 via Bluetooth.
I searched a lot for tutorial but I didn't find any related tutorial. Please anyone help with this or any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know very little about Bluetooth and this answer may be dated or poor practice, but at least it works. If anyone knows better, please provide a better answer and I will delete this.

So, I have two Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian. I installed `BlueDot` on both with:

```
sudo pip3 install bluedot
```

I then [paired](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pairpipi.html) them, running this on the first:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# pairable on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# default-agent
```

and this on the second:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# pairable on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# default-agent
[bluetooth]# scan on
```

When the first RasPi (hostname=pi4) showed up, I paired with it by typing this in the second RasPi:

```
[bluetooth]# pair DC:A6:32:03:0C:1B
```

Then I quit `bluetoothctl` on both.

Then I ran this server code (attributable to [here](https://github.com/martinohanlon/BlueDot/blob/master/examples/server_debug.py)) on the first RasPi **UNDER `sudo`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bluedot.btcomm import BluetoothServer
from time import sleep
from signal import pause

def data_received(data):
    print("recv - {}".format(data))
    server.send(data)

def client_connected():
    print("client connected")

def client_disconnected():
    print("client disconnected")

print("init")
server = BluetoothServer(
    data_received,
    auto_start = False,
    when_client_connects = client_connected,
    when_client_disconnects = client_disconnected)

print("starting")
server.start()
print(server.server_address)
print("waiting for connection")

try:
    pause()
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    print("cancelled by user")
finally:
    print("stopping")
    server.stop()
print("stopped")
```

And this code (attributable to [here](https://github.com/martinohanlon/BlueDot/blob/master/examples/client_debug.py)) on the second, also under `sudo`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bluedot.btcomm import BluetoothClient
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from signal import pause

def data_received(data):
    print("recv - {}".format(data))

print("Connecting")
c = BluetoothClient("pi4", data_received)

print("Sending")
try:
    while True:
        c.send("hi {} \n".format(str(datetime.now())))
        sleep(1)
finally:
    c.disconnect()
```

The two RasPis swapped messages successfully till interrupted. I measured the Round Trip Time (RTT) and it averaged around 30ms between two RasPi 4 placed around a metre apart.

It may be better to add the `pi` user to the `dialout` Linux group (or some other one) rather than run under `sudo`. If anyone knows, please say.

Comment: `sudo` isn't generally needed for interacting with Bluetooth with either `bluetoothctl` or `bluedot`.  The exception to this has been "Raspberry Raspberry Pi OS *Lite*"

Comment: @ukBaz Ok, thank you. I found I needed `sudo` on my system as it didn't work without.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for answering my question. It works :)

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi, I wanted to know that, Is it possible to connect and communicate with multiple raspberry pi via Bluetooth? Is there any limit? If possible can we create one server and multiple clients on above answer?

Comment: @Ganesh I'm sorry, I don't know and I only have 2 RasPis to play with. I don't see why it wouldn't be possible though. I would suggest you ask a new question, adding a link to this one, and ask all the Bluetooth experts on Stack Overflow rather than just me. Also, just try it - you have the code so what's to lose? Good luck.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you:)