# Convenient way to save raspberry pi sensor data on a laptop in the same network

Tags: python, database, raspberry-pi, sensors

I have 3 raspberry pi. Each of them has 8 sensors connected. They will send sensor datas every minute. I have to store the data on a laptop for 2 months. This setup will be in a different place so I have to make sure everything works perfectly.

What is the most convenient way to communicate and store the data?

I have read about using MQTT subscriber on desktop and store the data on the database. Is there any easier way? I am new to this so apology for the simple questions :(

Comment: *convenient way to communicate* you are asking about communication between sensors and raspberries XOR between raspberries and your laptop?

Comment: between raspberry and the laptop

Comment: Do you have solid wifi available? Do you have Bluetooth available? Do you have serial available? What are the distances between the devices? How much data does each sensor produce per minute? 8 floats? 4 GB?

Comment: I think the question is too vague to provide a decent answer. You may want to try posting on [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) as this is more an architecture question, but you'll need to give more information. How do you need to access the data after it's been collected? Do you have a database? Will the laptop be running for 2 months solid or will the pi's need to cache the historic data and send it periodically? What do you mean by 'convenient'? I usually start by sending all sensor data to a MQTT broker but that may not be right for you?

Comment: I would certainly try to store the data locally on each RasPi in case communications are down between RasPi and laptop, in addition to sending it to the laptop. MQTT is probably as good as anything though that doesn't actually store the data - it just distributes it. You might look at InfluxDB.

Comment: There are several options described in my answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64647027/2836621

Comment: Hello? Have you abandoned this question?