# Transfer measured data form Raspberry Pi to a Laptop in real-time

Tags: python, c, linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi zero which measures data from some sensors (acceleration, gyro, ...). My goal it to send the measured data in real-time to my Laptop (Linux) and plot them as a graph.

So far I make a "Hotspot" with my Laptop to which the Raspberry connects. After this I can set up a ssh connection between my Laptop and the Raspberry and execute programs. I also can print the data with `printf(data)` so that i can see it in the terminal on the Laptop. My problem is that i don't know, what the best way is to tranfer and plot the data.

I already have some ideas how i can implement the transfer but i have the feeling that I'm overthinking it and there is a much easier concept (e.g. python library).

Does a good concept for this exist or has somebody a good idea how i can implement this?

`Note:` i can write the program which measure the data in c or python. So I will take the one which makes the transfer easier to implement.

Comment: Might be easier to serve HTTPS on the Pi and have laptop periodically poll.

Comment: May by netcat (nc) use..

Comment: Several ideas here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64647027/2836621